# Utilities.formatDate() gives wrong date/time

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timezone

I read a cell in a google sheet which is a date (it reads it correctly) and then I attempt to reformat it using the `Utilities.formatDate()` method. All I really want to do is drop the "minutes" from the time so it looks like:

```
9/11/2023 10:02 am
```

In debug mode, the date is correct when read, but the `formatDate` method gives the wrong results.

I looked at timezone in both Sheets and AppScript - and there is no way to make them the same (that I see) because the list of choices is different in the two platforms. Not sure what to do.

I am trying to use `GMT-4 Eastern Standard Time / New York` which I can do fine in app script but there is no such one listed in Google Sheets.

Any advice would be welcome

Comment: Could you provide [mcve]?

Answer (score 2):

You can probably resolve you issue with just formatting the cell.  Using information from [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats?hl=en#date_and_time_format_patterns)

Here's a simple script with same date and different formats

```
function lfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  sh.getRange("A1:D1").setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormats([["mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss", "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm", "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM","mmm dd, yyyy hh:mm am/pm"]]);
}
```

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 09/11/22 16:43:40 | 09/11/2022 16:43 | 09/11/2022 04:43 PM | Sep 11, 2022 04:43 PM |